# Edge case when calculating Area of pixel values using Integral image

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection

I'm trying to implement the Viola Jones algorithm for face detection.

I thought I understood the whole feature concept and how to calculate the area of pixel values using an integral image. However, the way I've implemented it is throwing an exception. I realized it is because there is an edge case when the height or width of the area to calculate is 1.

[image: Calculate area using Integral Image]

The method described when using the integral image causes the value of the area to be = C - (B + D) + A.

However, if let's say the height is 1 pixel, then B = C and A = D. The equation fails and equals zero.

How do you calculate the area if the width or height is 1? I made a diagram displaying the issues involved for a height of 1

:[image: Diagram of area issue]

I considered just ignoring D and C and simply doing B - A, while it works for box1 and box2, it doesn't work for box 3 and 4. Also it's probably a coincidence it works for box1 and box 2, since if I wanted the area for the 3rd row's 2 middle values and nothing else (integral values 6 and 9), the difference is 3, not 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated